# Tanach without trup and nikudos

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

Where can I get a tanach without nikudos and trop in book form? It should be the whole tanach and not just the haftoras. It can be side by side with nikudos and trop like a tikun or just straight text.

Comment: Would a website with this suffice? What do you want it for?

Comment: like this? https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0101.htm

Comment: http://www.lashon.net/CL/Tanach/Tikkun.cgi'

Comment: https://il.bidspirit.com/ui/lotPage/source/catalog/auction/5393/lot/132187/%D7%AA%D7%A0-%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8-%D7%90-%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9D-%D7%AA%D7%A1-%D7%90?lang=he

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that you are interested in learning to sing other parts of the Tanach that are not usually read and therefore not found in a typical Tikkun.
I would recommend carefully cutting post-it notes into strips, and covering above and below the letters.  You could just read it that way, or you could make a photocopy if the post-its get too messy to leave on.
I would also recommend consulting with your Rav, as to how to optimally focus you learning.
Hatzlacha! - Papa

Comment: That is very time consuming and it will cost a lot for al those post its